# Download all files as zip when button is clicked

Tags: php

I can't understand how my button should look and trigger download files as zip. On the page I can add files in some sort of cart and when I finish with file adding I want to download them like zip.

So what I have so far is this

```
<?php
include 'database.inc.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['total_cart_items']))
{
   echo count($_SESSION['itemid']);
   exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['item_id']))
{    
    if (!in_array($_POST['item_id'], $_SESSION['itemid'])) $_SESSION['itemid'][]=$_POST['item_id'];
    echo count($_SESSION['itemid']);
    exit();
}  

if(! isset($_POST['showcart'])) exit;
foreach ($_SESSION['itemid'] as $i):

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM document_upload WHERE upload_id = :id"; 
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(":id", $i);
    $result->execute();                 

    $resArray = $result->fetchAll();

     foreach ( $resArray as $row ):?>

         <div class="cart_items">
              <a style="text-align:center;" href=""><p><?=$row["upload_title"]?> - <?=$row["upload_description"]?></p></a>
         </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
         <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" style="margin: 10px;" href="">Download All Files</a>
```

So do I need another file which will load when I click on `Download All Files` or?

EDIT: I found this. The problem is how to pass all the files for download to this function?

```
session_start();
$files = array();

$valid_files = array();
if(is_array($files)) {
  foreach($files as $file) {
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        $valid_files[] = $file;
    }
  }
}

if(count($valid_files > 0)){
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $zip_name = "zipfile.zip";
   if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
      $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

foreach($valid_files as $file){
    $zip->addFile($file);
}

$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name)){
    // force to download the zip
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    readfile($zip_name);
    // remove zip file from temp path
    unlink($zip_name);
}

} else {
    echo "No valid files to zip";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Welll, currently that anchor (the `<a>` tag you here call "button") does not do anything, since it has no target defined. So you would need some javascript function to handle a click event, but you did not mention any such thing. So the question is: what do you want to happen if that button is clicked? I assume that archive to be created, so you need to call a script on the server, something like `download.php`...

Comment: I have update my question. So first how to pass all the files to the download.php ..

Comment: Typically you do not pass over all files, but they are already present in the server side session, since they have been added before. But we cannot help with that, since you did not post any details about how you implemented that "cart" you refer to.

Comment: @arkascha I have edited my question again and I added full source which add and display items on cart. Cart is populated via ajax call and I send just `item_id` to this file nothing more.

Comment: OK, so you already have your answer: in the first snippet of your code you can see how the files contained in that "cart" are read from your database to be listed. So I assume that in the second script you posted, which should apparently create that archive, you can do the same...

Comment: Well I put `download.php` on the href and when I click on the link is just open blank page and nothing happen

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected. Two reasons: 1. in that snippet you just try to use a variable called `$files`, but that variable has never been defined in that script. Where should the content you try to use come from? And 2. you simply ignored my last comment.

Comment: So, do I need to include this file which save session with files in the `download.php`? p.s. I didn't ignore your comment.. I just don't understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109329/discussion-between-arkascha-and-john).